# zk internationalization by LabelLocator

Tags: internationalization, zk

I'm tring to make zk internationalization in my project. I have looked through all docs and find out this info:

```
public class FooServletLocator implements org.zkoss.util.resource.LabelLocator {
    private ServletContext _svlctx;
    private String _name;
    public FooServletLocator(ServletContext svlctx, String name) {
        _svlctx = svlctx;
        _name = name;
    }
    public URL locate(Locale locale) {
        return _svlctx.getResource("/WEB-INF/labels/" + name + "_" + locale + ".properties");
    }
}
```

Then i should invoke this locator by code:

```
Labels.register(LabelLocator2)
```

The question is where should i put this codeline and invoke locator, in my viewmodel (i use mvvm) or somewhere else? I can't understand it :(

Thanks for any help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Internationalization/Labels) about ZK internationalization are quite straightforward. It seems you just do not have read up a couple of paragraphs:

> Then, we could register label locators when the application starts by use of WebAppInit as follows.

```java
public class MyAppInit implements org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.WebAppInit {
    public void init(WebApp wapp) throws Exception {
        Labels.register(new FooDBLocator(("moduleX");
        Labels.register(new FooDBLocator(("moduleY");
        Labels.register(new FooServletLocator((ServletContext)wapp.getNativeContext(), "module-1");
        Labels.register(new FooServletLocator((ServletContext)wapp.getNativeContext(), "module-2");
    }
}
```

> where we assume moduleX and moduleY is the database table to load the properties, and module-1.properties and module-2.properties are two modules of messages you provide. Then, you configure it in WEB-INF/zk.xml as described in [ZK Configuration Reference](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Configuration_Reference/zk.xml/The_listener_Element/The_org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.WebAppInit_interface).

Comment: Ok thanks. But will  i be able to switch between different locators dynamically on page by combobox for example? I mean how not to write same parts of html code for different languages
and just to write one expression and it will be named according to chosen language.

Comment: @SergeBud, of course. To access i18n labels use `labels` object in `zul` files or `Labels.getLabel(...)` in Java. And you can call `Labels.reset()` to dynamically reload labels if the locale has been changed. Read more details in the same doc.